# How to connect two paired bluetooth devices

Tags: android

How to connect two paired bluetooth devices using android programaticaly.that suppose two devices are already paired,but not connected.So how should i get the mac adress of the paired devices?

Comment: You're going to have to specify more about what you want or what you're confused about if we are supposed to help you.

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273084/how-to-programatically-connect-2-android-devices-with-bluetooth

Comment: Before posting here, you should have a look at the official docs, which includes a [step by step guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [Bluetooth Chat sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html), that comes with the SDK?