# How do i send information via a setup bluetooth connection

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

So im working around with bluetooth and trying to figure out how to send two strings via a bluetooth connection. From one android device to another.

I found this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
but it talks alot about setting up the connection. So i went straight down to the chapter about Managing a Connection. The reason i do this is that in the apps i create i plan to setup the bluetooth connection before opening the apps (via the phones usual bluetooth setup) and then open the apps and send when it is necessary.

So my question is how do i find the bluetooth socket that should be setup? Since that should be what im searching for to create the sending and recieving threads?

Hope this is enough information, else tell what more you need and ill try and answer to the best of my ability.

Best Regards Drakthal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual bluetooth setup only pairs between devices, it doesn't create a data connection between them (And even if it would, you wouldn't be able to access this `Socket` object because it's not created in your process).

After Bluetooth is turned on, you can call `BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()` to get a set of the paired devices. You can then iterate over them, and initiate a connection to the one you want. You *can't* avoid the connection creation :( If you want a simplified example, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273084/how-to-programatically-connect-2-android-devices-with-bluetooth/7934426#7934426) (An answer I posted a while ago, regarding the whole pairing/connecting/sending/receiving subject with bluetooth).

Once you acquired an open connection, sending the 2 string is easy.

```
String s1 = "A", s2 = "B";
byte[] buf1 = s1.getBytes(), buf2 = s2.getBytes();
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(buf1);
os.write(buf2);
os.flush();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, looked over your guide and there's only one thing im not entirely sure about. The UUID needed how do i exactly create that since i guess i will need to create two similar UUID's for the sockets.

Comment: "To get a UUID to use with your application, you can use one of the many random UUID generators on the web, then initialize a UUID with fromString(String)." You can use this generator: http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen

Comment: Ahhh thanks, got that working now. One more thing, you write that he should connect in a seperate thread, so should i create 1 thread for connecting and another thread for sending and recieving data or is one enough for thoose tasks?

Comment: One is enough - the connect thread dies anyway after the connection was established.

Comment: Ok now everything on the clientside should work. And the connection part of the serverside should as well. The only thing i need now is the read method of the thread and how to parse it on. Have to get it done tonight. Should i make a new question where i show the important code on the serverside, and if so would you be able to look and see if you could help?

Comment: Well, you could open a new question... But it's quite simple. You get the byte array from the `read` method, then convert it to a string this way: `String s = new String(bytes)`;

Comment: Since its two strings in a row does it know when the first string is done sending and when the next will start to be sent?

Comment: You can send a seperator between the 2 strings.